# Ember ember-simple-auth override routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated in application route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, overriding, ember-simple-auth

How do you override the `routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated`?

And once that happens, how can it transition to a route with a dynamic segment?

I realize I can override `sessionAuthenticated`; and in that ways override the functionality of `routeAfterAuthentication`.  However, `routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated` is a computed property that is executed in a `beforeModel` in the `unauthenticated-route-mixin.js` mixin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app/session/route.js`, just do:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import UnauthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/unauthenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(UnauthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated: 'dashboard'
});
```

and it works, no more:

> Error while processing route: session.login Assertion Failed: The route index was not found Error

---

The following works as well, but is **deprecated**

In `config/environment.js`:

```
var ENV = {
   ...
};

ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
   // authenticationRoute:          'login',
   // routeAfterAuthentication:     'dashboard',
   routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated:  'dashboard'
};
```

Comment: For details on available options, see the API docs: http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/Configuration.html

Comment: I don't even remember why I wrote this question. lol.  However, if you mention there is not an certain error that does not come up anymore I am assuming there was an update that addressed whatever it was I was concerned about.  Thanks.